# VB.Net 2010 Forms Based Authentication Errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, webforms, forms-authentication

I am following the codeguru tutorial [codeguru tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c19359/Using-ASPNET-to-Make-a-Secure-Site-and-Move-Login-Processing-Out-of-the-Page.htm) yes its in c# but I cannot find a good VB example.

Initially I am having trouble with the web config file. The tutorial states to do this

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx"
protection="All" path="/" />

</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<location path="test.aspx">

<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>

</location>
```

Now that fails because XML can not have multiple root level documents and if I insert location into the system.web block it errors with system.web has invalid child element location.

I have referred to msdn [MSDN ASP.NET authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) however its examples are incorrect or maybe outdated as it example has a 'forms' error as it is not an allowed attribute.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms forms="401kApp" loginUrl="/login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Can anyone clarify how this works? I cannot find an accurate walk-through or example for this, if you have located an accurate VB.NET guide if you could show me one that would be very helpful.

As an aside I also found this [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication) example tutorial again in c# but it had enumerate errors from the start with just creating the login pages so can't use this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<location>` element needs to go directly inside the root `<configuration>` element.

Comment: I have a blank webconfig file that I am filling myself as I started with an empty project. Sorry I should have written that.

Comment: I highly recommend that you start from a template, to avoid these (and more) issues.

Comment: thanks can't college requirement so that we understand all components included in our application. found a example here http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/16/visual-studio-2010-web-config-transforms.aspx

Comment: That's a good idea, but you can't begin to understand the components before you know what they are.  I recommend that you explore a built-in template, make sure you understand every line of it, _and then_ start from scratch.